# Using variable in glob.iglob Python

Tags: python, glob

I'm trying to iterate over all json files in a directory, which is also function argument. However I get an empty list. Part of the code in question is:

```
   def function_process_files(auth_method, somedir):
       ...
       ...
       for file in glob.iglob(somedir'/test_*.json'):
           maipulate(file)
       ...
```

The directory provided with **somedir** is subdirectory of the current directory where Python script is being run.

Comment: `somedir + '/test_*.json'` or `f'{somedir}/test_*.json'`

Comment: Thanks a lot @KlausD.! Works like a charm. BTW haven't ever seen the second construction.